# Accessing elements inside a div on calling of a function inside that div among several similar divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making the following form:

[image]

Here firstly the user clicks on "ADD ANOTHER CATEGORY" which duplicates every thing from category name to the last add more button. Let us assume we clicked the button once so now we have two category blocks. Now the user can input the details in the two blocks. On click on "ADD MORE" button the form shall show another row of inputs of item,quantity and price in that category block. It works accordingly only for the first category block.

For the second category block if I click "ADD MORE" inside that then it does not increments the item,quantity and price input for the 2nd category block instead it always increments it for the 1st category block.

following is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
      <label>Menu</label>
      <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12" id="category">
      <div class="row" id="categoryContent">
          <div class="col s12">
              <h6>Categry name: </h6>
              <input type="text" name="category[]">
          </div>
          <div class="col s12"><h6>Veg</h6></div>
          <div class="col s12">
              <table>
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Item</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="veg">
                      <tr id="vegContent">
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="vitem[][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="vquantity[][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="vprice[][]">
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addVeg()" type="button">Add More</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12"><h6>Non-Veg</h6></div>
          <div class="col s12">
              <table>
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Item</th>
                      <th>Quantity</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="nonVeg">
                      <tr id="nonVegContent">
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="nitem[][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="nquantity[][]">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" name="nprice[][]">
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addNonVeg()" type="button">
                  Add More
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12" style="text-align: center">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="addCategory()" type="button">
          Add Another Category
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my js code:

```
function addCategory(){
    $("#category").append($("#categoryContent").clone());
}

function addVeg(){
    $("#veg").append($("#vegContent").clone());
};

function addNonVeg(){
    $("#nonVeg").append($("#nonVegContent").clone());
};
```

I want that on click on "ADD MORE" button shall increment the input line inside that block only.

Comment: its not a good practice that in one document you have different snippets with same id.Try to give them different ids.Also pass an argument 'this' to check the location of button where the button is present that will help you get its parent element and thus adding vegContent to that particular element.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element by common class(you can add class to each element) like

```
<input type="text" name="nitem[][]" class="itemname">
```

So that you can access it as follows:

```
$('.itemname').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var value = currentElement.val(); 
});
```

**OR**

You can add distinct value to each element as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="nitem[][]" id="Item1">
<input type="text" name="nitem[][]" id="Item2">
```

and you can access it.

```
$('#Item1').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to clone all elements,then you can append it to another div,I made some correction in the your provided code,Now it working for me.

`

```
function addCategory(){
      $('#category').clone().appendTo('#categoryContent');
}
function addVeg(){
    //$("#veg").append($("#vegContent").clone());
    $('#veg').clone().appendTo('#vegContent');
};

function addNonVeg(){
    $('#nonVeg').clone().appendTo('#nonVegContent');
};
```

`

Comment: you did not understand it

Comment: I made some correction (adding some div to clone element ).Just take a look,hope it may help http://www.learnwithdevayan.co.nf/TEST.html

Comment: This is already what i am doing man... I dont want this but... I want that the input appends on the category block only... In your code also it is only appending for 1st category block only